# Css is not applying 100%

Tags: html, css

Following is my [URL] in which only on the first bullet of the slider  the css is not being 100% applied. I created its content in plain html in tables and then copy that into actual site, in plain html everything is working fine but not at the place where it should work fine.
I tried to make the left coulmn image Vertically top align, Tried to put line space after `awarded most innovative in LTC` and also make the whole table center aligned but dont know why the css is not being 100% applied. Kindly help.

`Note:I worked in inline styling`

[URL]

Comment: Don't use tables for layout. Do perform [basic automated error checking](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fcaremerge.us%2FWebsite%2Fweb1%2Find.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).

Comment: @Quentin agreed i have converted it in divs now and seems that its working kindly just let me know one last thing how can i make div center aligned `Is the only way to make it center aligned by margin-left property or the like?` . Its the last issue currently i am facing Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Center Aligned div

```
div.myDiv {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

You define a width of the div. then use margin auto.